# Dynamic columns in Primefaces datatable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I want to create a dynamic datatable using Primefaces that reflects user's choice. The user can choose one of the two radio buttons and then the datatable will be shown to the user.

The only difference between two radio buttons is that choosing the second one the datatable will contain an additional column.

Is it possible to create such datatable, using Primefaces and JSF?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution would be to set rendered attribute of column depending on radio button selected.

```
...
<h:column rendered="#{myBean.radioValue}">
...
```

radio button 1 -> `myBean.radioValue=false`
radio button 2 -> `myBean.radioValue=true`

Comment: how to get the value of the radio button that is checked from the xhtml to the bean ??

Comment: So was my answer beneficial?

Comment: it 's very helpful 
but i didn't know how he gets the value from the xhtml to the bean 
he use in the code favColor1 , favColor2 and favColor3 that doesn't figure out in the bean just in the declaration and he setter end the getter

Comment: Setters and getters are omitted intentionally to make it readable. He noted see - "`//getter and setter methods `"

Comment: i didn't know how he got the value of radio button despite in the bean he didn't use it those variables !

Comment: finally i find a solution :)